# how can i send html form data to node.js server by making ajax call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, node.js

I want to send form data to node.js server using Ajax and I am fallowing the below approach to send data.

I am not getting how receive it in node.js server program I am not using express framework for node.js

client.HTML

```
<script>
 function myFunction() {
   var region = document.getElementById("region").value;
   var os = document.getElementById("os").value;
   var data = {};
   data.region = region;
   data.os = os;
   $.ajax({
     type: 'post',
     datatype: 'jsonp',
     data: JSON.stringify(data),
     contentType: 'application/json',
     url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8083/', //node.js server is running
     success: function(data) {
       alert("success");

     }
   });

</script>
<form>
<select id="region" name="region" class="region"></select>
<select id="os" name="os" class="os"></select>  
<input type="button" value="search" class="fil_search" onclick="myFunction()"/>
</form>
```

server.js

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var url = require('url');
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var assert = require('assert')
var ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectID;
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app     = express();
var result1=[];
var result2=[];
var result3=[];
var result4=[];
var result5=[];
var result6=[];
var result7=[];
var i=0;
var region;
var os;
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); 

MongoClient.connect("mongodb://192.168.1.22:27017/test", function(err, db) {

if(err) { return console.dir(err); }
else {
app.get('/',function(req, res) {

var url_parts = url.parse(req.url, true);
var url_parsed = url.parse(req.url, true);

"i want data here from ajax to perform"

console.log("connected");


var instance = db.collection('instance');
var region = db.collection('region');

region.findOne(({$and: [{"region_name": region_name},{"os_type": os}]}), function(err, result){
if(err){    
throw(err);
}
else{
console.log(region);
var newr = result.inst_name;

instance.find({ "inst_id": { "$in": newr } }).toArray(function(err, resultn){
if(err){
throw(err);
}
else{       
    var len=resultn.length;

    console.log(resultn);
    console.log(len);

    for(var i=0;i<len;i++)
    {
        result1[i]=resultn[i].inst_type;
        result2[i]=resultn[i].vcpu;
        result3[i]=resultn[i].memory_gib;
        result4[i]=resultn[i].storage;
        result5[i]=resultn[i].phy_processor;
        result6[i]=resultn[i].clock_spd;
        result7[i]=resultn[i].netwk_pef;            
    }
    var wstream = fs.createWriteStream('myOutput.txt');
    wstream.write(result1.toString()+"~"+result2.toString());       
    //var str = "Hi man"
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type':'text/html'});
    //res.end(url_parsed.query.callback+'("'+resultn.toString()+'")'); 
    res.end(url_parsed.query.callback+'("'+result1.toString()+"~"+result2.toString()+"~"
    +result3.toString()+"~"+result4.toString()+"~"+result5.toString()+"~"+result6.toString()
    +"~"+result7.toString()+'")');      
}
});
}
}); 
}).listen(process.env.PORT || 8083);
```

}
});

I am not getting how to receive data in node.js server program and after receiving data I want process on that data and send back processed data to same HTML page.

Comment: Is this your actual code? You have in both the server and the client code a syntax error which will prevent the code from running at all. You say `I am not using express`, but `app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));`  looks like epress, so you should tell which framework you use instead of express.

Comment: it is actual code but i have pasted imp part of my code where i want to send and recieve data from HTML form. just i want a solution how to get the data in node.js server?

Comment: Ok but you have a syntax error here `'("' + result1.toString()'");`  so your server code wont run at all. And you have a missing `}`  at the end of your `myFunction`  function on the client side, so this code won't run either. And you still didn't tell what framework you use instead of express. What is `app` if not an `express` application?

Comment: @t.niese pls check my progrm once again i have uploaded full working program and pls give me solution. how to receive a data in node.js server and i want query it on and again send back data to that HTML page

Comment: please somebody help me to get resolve this.thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have `app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));` in your server.js file then using bodyParser you can retrieve data from ajax as given below:

```
app.post('/', function(req, res) { //your ajax should also post to url: '/'
    var region = req.body.region,
    os = req.body.os;
    // ...
});
```